What is difference between client/src/tpu_client.rs and client/src/nonblocking/tpu_client.rs
I'm using client/src/tpu_client.rs to send tx directly to TPU using my owner RPC, using 'send_wire_transaction', i see both versions have this method
Also how i can set tpu ip and port?

To answer the question, the nonblocking version of the TPU client (client/src/nonblocking/tpu_client.rs) is meant to work in async contexts, but the blocking version (client/src/tpu_client.rs) is meant for sync / blocking contexts.
If you have an RPC server though, you don't need to use this -- you can send transactions directly to your RPC, which will broadcast the transaction to the TPU port on the appropriate leader validators in the network.
